# SQL retrieving date times in wrong format when creating index

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to create a index for a view that I have. The problem is that this was not schema bound view, so changed that with an alter command. Next problem i'm having is that it has to be an Unique Clustered index. So i thought no problem but while my colum does not contain a duplicate key value, it still is complaining that there is one. In the error i saw that:
it says: "The duplicate key value is (Dec  7 2012 10:02AM)."

While in my columns its stored as: 2012-12-07 10:02:58.710

So because he reduces the granularity it complains about duplicate key values... 
The command i used was:

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX testIndex ON dbo.View_BookmarksWithCreatorName (BM_CreateDate)

Tried searching for it, but didn't quite find anything. How can i make sure that when creating the index, it does not change the format, but just takes it as it is stored in the column?

*EDIT*

Since it was an existing view, without schema bounding, I just used the ALTER command:

```
ALTER VIEW dbo.View_BookmarksWithCreatorName WITH SCHEMABINDING 

AS

SELECT BM_Key,BM_ID, BM_LastUpdate, BM_Caption, BM_Comment, BM_CreateDate, BM_DateTime, BM_Duration, BM_Type, BM_Value, BM_CreatorUserKey, BM_SourceID, BM_Category
FROM dbo.Bookmarks,dbo.Users
```

Comment: You have both a mysql and sql-server tag.  Do you have two databases with the same problem?

Comment: Changed that, was kinda not paying attention when adding tags, sry.

Comment: Put the `CREATE VIEW` statement in the question as well.

Comment: There is no reason why the index would reduce the precision unless there are implicit/explicit casts going on within the view. [This example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/20833/1) shows no loss of precision.

Comment: Edited for alteration of the view. I know there should not be any reason, but this is all i'm doing...

Comment: What would that view definition mean to you? It is just a cross product of two tables. And you also don't query and Users column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result is a cartesian product of bookmarks and users:

```
FROM    dbo.Bookmarks,dbo.Users
```

Is equivalent to:

```
FROM    dbo.Bookmarks
        CROSS JOIN dbo.Users
```

i.e. Every bookmark will be duplicated for every user since there is no criteria linking the two tables. So unless your user table only has one record in it then `BM_CreateDate` cannot be unique in the view, even if it is unique in the source table.